# Having issue with jruby and spree erb templates

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jruby, erb, spree

I am having hard time with spree 1.3.0 and jruby 1.7.1. As it seems jruby is not able to parse erb templates, and sometimes gives errors with string assignment which doesn't make any sense, since changing ruby to 1.9.3 works very well(Yes, with no error!).

I tried this with WEBrick and Trinidad, both are behaving the same way.

I would be very grateful if you can give me any idea on what's happening here, why?, and what could be the possible way to fix this. Thanks!

Do let me know if you need anything from me, like Gemfile or any environment settings.

Please see this image for reference below:

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to include an ERB template that is causing you trouble so that we can check it, even though you say it works on MRI. Is there any reason you must use ERB? There are plenty of other template libraries you could try (all of them have surpassed venerable ERB, in my opinion).

Comment: @iain ERB is being included by rails itself. And, I can make use of other template engine like haml, but, spree's all view templates are written in ERB, so I can re-write them all to other template engine's structure. I figured out a couple of days ago that, it's a problem with `deface` gem which isn't being treated by `jruby` here. I guess I'll have to fork and see if I can do something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that, it's a problem with jruby which is treating deface gem in a weird way. I guess spree will need sometime to switch to jruby. For now closing this question since there is no answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

In practice Deface has the most utility in the Admin when customizing Spree.  Its my opinion as well as many others.

When using JRuby I've used the following setting:
 Rails.application.config.deface.enabled = false